# Facebook signed_request data and some security concearns

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, html

We've just developed a small Facebook puzzle that people win some gifts from our customer. I'd like to ask a few questions since I'm pretty stuck despite tried lots of things. First I'd like to write what we have and then will explain our problems.

**What we did so far:**

- Root of application (/) checks for signed_request in POST params, extracts information from it to see if we've registered the logged in user into our database. This checks are also used to understand if the request is sent from Facebook or not to prevent requests coming outside of Facebook. (will write why we want this)
- Once the application is successfully rendered, Facebook JS API takes place, does its checks and sets the fbsr cookie. We use that cookie information while processing ajax requests to check if the request really belongs to the logged in user (e.g.: scores being sent for a user belong to the logged in user).
- We implemented CSRF protection and another protection to check if the requests are POST and more specifically AJAX requests and return 40x if not.

**Problems:**

- Despite I do some checks to prevent spoofed scores, I couldn't think of a way that the logged in user could improve its own scores by simply calling the same JS code I do for real scores. We just ignored this for some time until we just found out that some people seem to take advantage of this bug.
- One way I thought of is to ignore all requests except coming from Facebook. Since the ajax requests are blocked (cross site) we should have been safe. However this leaded to another problem that, once we redirect users to e.g. leaderboard the signed_request data is lost and our index page returns 40x once the user tries to go back since our application thinks that the user tries to visit our application outside of Facebook.

I hope that I made our problem clear. Gaming time is calculated by Flash (game is programmed in AS3) and it's sent via JavaScript methods to server side. We could have done it in Flash but that only prevents our problem from becoming trivial. Afterall we'd have the same problem if we had implemented the game in HTML5.

Any thoughts, suggestions are really welcome and thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Maybe you can implement the game on the server side and just let the clients to send their actions to server. I do not know about your game much, but I believe this is the only way to be sure of trusted clients. A great read: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug by design. You are calculating the scores on client side and then send them to the server. The server has no way to validate if the score is correct. This can ALWAYS be faked by clever users.

Never ever ever calculate things that could give users advantage on clientside. Clientside is evil. Everything on clientside can be manipulated - no matter how hard you try.

Calculate your scores on the server and use the client side only to display them. Every other solution is crackable.